# Facebook not fetching image while sharing

Tags: joomla-3.4, facebook

I am Using latest Joomla 3.4 and Easy Like and Share Module. When I share anything to facebook, it doesn't fetch image, but fetch only title and image. It was working fine but it suddenly stopped today. I don't know what is wrong with it, however I have not changed anything in back-end.

I tried Facebook debug tool and getting following;

Object at URL 'http://www.livemedia24.com/videos/7262-arrested-workers-of-mqm-are-also-workers-of-bjp-party-in-india-rao-anwar-ssp' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

I even put app id in Easy Like and Share Module but still facing same issue. I would appreciate if someone can help in this regard.

Gzip is disable, I even cleared cache.

Comment: I would suggest you contact the developer of this module

Comment: I even tried RsSocial Module and few others, but same issue :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Facebook Debug, it is fetching an image now.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livemedia24.com%2Fvideos%2F7262-arrested-workers-of-mqm-are-also-workers-of-bjp-party-in-india-rao-anwar-ssp

** og:image ** =>

https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCOFTCb1Rf803Ux&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livemedia24.com%2Fmedia%2Fcom_hwdmediashare%2Ffiles%2Fd0%2F7a%2Fcd%2Fdd5062cf4323359b68cc783453f35518.jpg

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have changed couple of settings and now its fetching image, but the problem remain same, it dosent show image on page. You can see: "When shared, this is what will be included"

Comment: Check it again in a couple of days - Facebook has a big cache.